# Unable to log in to wp admin after migrating and changing urls

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, database-migration

Front end is working fine and site is displaying as it should however we are unable to log in to wp admin. When entering user name and password and clicking log in the page refreshes without any error messages. (the same happens when you enter a wrong password too)

We did have some issues during the migration with looping urls and wonder if maybe this has something to do with it? Have tried clearing cache / cookies and have tried disabling pluggins.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using reset password link from Wordpress?

If it still does not work, I recommend you to reset it from Phpmyadmin (see guide here http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, yes we have tried resetting the password using Phpmyadmin. There is no error message when trying to log in wp admin, the form just refreshes no matter what you type in

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you migrate the WP site to somewhere else you may need to set the Path of your site first than you will be able to login.

open wp-config.php and placed following lines after database connection.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'new_site_url');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'new_site_url');
```

After this refresh your admin side page and try to login now.

Comment: we have set the paths in wp-config but still have the same issue

Comment: can you please try to login at following url:
yoursiteurl.com/wp-login.php

Comment: yeah that is the url what we have been using to try and log in but unsuccessful

Answer (score -1):

Please Check Under General settings make sure
*WordPress Address (URL)* 
*Site Address (URL)*

are in the same url otherwise the is_user_looged_in() will not work